# Make Variable entirely global without global keyword

Tags: python, variables

I want to make variables that I can use in each function without using the global keyword, just want to save code, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `globals()['variablename']`

Comment: There's no way to make a pervasive declaration of global variables, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to declare such variables in another module.

For example, with the following directory structure,

```
├ __init__.py
├ var.py
└ main.py
```

`var.py`:

```
val = 1
```

`main.py`:

```
import var 


def func1():
    var.val += 1


def func2():
    var.val += 1


print(var.val)  # 1
func1()
print(var.val)  # 2
func2()
print(var.val)  # 3
```

Comment: it gives me an error, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'var'"

Comment: @x3- I added directory structure. Please create a new module `var.py` beside your main script.